# Size of returned array from function

Tags: arrays, vbscript

You can use `UBound` to determine the size of an array. I want to that that to an array returned as a result of a function, but then I get the error `Invalid procedure call`. This is the (simplified) function:

```
Public Function GetCheckBlocks(fileName)
    Dim counter, checkBlocks
    Set checkBlocks = CreateObject( "System.Collections.ArrayList" )

    For counter = 0 To 10
      checkBlocks.Add counter
    Next

    Set GetCheckBlocks = checkBlocks
End Function
```

And here is the way I call the function and want to get the size of the array:

```
Dim expectedChecks, expectedFile
expectedFile = "test.txt"

Set expectedChecks = GetCheckBlocks(expectedFile)
MsgBox UBound(expectedChecks)
```

What is wrong here and how do I get the size of the returned array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns an ArrayList object, not an array. `UBound` only works with arrays. To get the number of elements contained in an ArrayList, use the `.Count` property:

```
expectedChecks.Count
```

Comment: Alternatively: have the function return `checkBlocks.ToArray` if you want/need a VBScript array.